# How to create grafana dashboard without time range?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I want to remove time range selector from grafana dashboard to not query for specific selected time range. I am using influxdb and I want to load all data without selecting specific time range and query with some where clausess. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dahboard setting enable `Hide time picker` and all InfluxDB queries write in the raw mode without time conditon (`$timeFilter` macro).